# Periodically create new ROS2 Nodes for all active topics

Tags: python, ros

I'm trying to update a list of names of active topics periodically . For this, the function get_active_topic_names() returns me a list of names of all currently used topics, however I'd like to call the function every X seconds in parallel to the Nodes already spinning so I'll be able to create new instances of my class ROS_SUB_WS_Pub and add these to the SPIN_QUEUE.

```
def main():
    SPIN_QUEUE = []
    rclpy.init()
    topic_list= get_active_topic_names()
    for top in topic_list:
        SPIN_QUEUE.append(ROS_Sub_WS_Pub(top))
    while rclpy.ok():
        try:
            for node in SPIN_QUEUE:
                rclpy.spin_once(node, timeout_sec=1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"something went wrong in the ROS Loop: {e}")
    rclpy.shutdown()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is threading needed here or how could I achieve a periodic call of my function so that the topics added after the program was initially ran are appended to the SPIN_QUEUE?

Comment: what about placing a call to `get_active_topic_names` in your loop ? Then you can compare the active topics to your existing nodes, and create new ones if necessary.